# Possible to sell goods that cater to non Muslims and other groups?

Tags: fiqh, business

I was wondering if it is possible to sell goods to non Muslims, specifically targeting them for the item, not something like a Cross pendant, rather something else like a band that says "Catholic" for example. This would be a play on the words cat a holic, but would be something that would probably attract Catholics that like cats. Would this be permissible, or would this fall in the same category as selling a Cross? Thank you in advance!